# Hibernate with Liquibase CustomTaskChange

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to develop application in Spring Boot. I would like to use Liquibase to load data from file and pass it to two tables connected with Many to Many relationship (so it will be 3 tables where one will hold id to another two). Is it a good way to do it with Liquibase?

I was trying to use customChange and develop own class which will read data from file and pass it to database with use of Hibernate EntityManager but it does not work. I am not able to create EntityMangerFactory or pass EntityManger with `@PersistenceContext` annotation. Is it any good way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same, but there are apparently better ways to do this. If you have a simple DB (which you do) it is good idea to create an ApplicationListener and react to application start. From there you can check if there are any entries in the repository and if there are none, you can load the model and save it with said repository.
More info [here](https://www.schakko.de/2017/11/07/how-to-programtically-insert-versionized-initial-data-into-spring-boot-applications/)